# Change a value of list java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an object (sonde(x,y,r,position)) whene i create a list of sonde i want to change value of position i use  :

```
    int sizel =arSonde.size();
    for(int i=0;i<sizel;i++){
       double x1=arSonde.get(i).x;
       double y1=arSonde.get(i).y;
       double rayn=arSonde.get(i).rayon;
       double x2=arrayAction.get(0).x;
       double y2=arrayAction.get(0).y;
       Random random=new Random();

       double D =rand.nextDouble();
       double rayA=arrayAct.get(0).rayon;
       if(D<rayA){
        arSonde.set(pos,5);
       }
```

i used:

```
list.set(pos,element);
```

Comment: Could you provide example input and expected output to make it clearer what you're asking? If you're asking about changing position of element in list, use Collections.swap(list, i, j);

Comment: No position it is a variable in the object sonde i add the object sonde to arSonde(arraylist) and when i test D with rayA i want to change the value of pos

Comment: Sonde is a class i instantiate an object from it
sonde contain:
double x,y,ray;
int pos;

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying set the position attribute of your Sonde object, and given your fields appear to be public...

```
arSonde.get(i).position = 5;
```

Your call `arSonde.set(pos, 5)` doesn't work because

- pos isn't defined, or at least not defined in the code you've shared
- set() expects (index, element) - index is the integer index within the array, not the name of field

If Sonde is immutable, or you needed a different instance you could always create a new instance and use the set(index, object) call...

```
arSonde.set(i, new Sonde(x1, y1, rayn, 5));
```